# RVM Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I've just deinstalled ruby version 2.1.0 via rvm to get rid of the message `"your current ruby version is 2.1.0 but your gemfile specifies 2.0.0"` but when I now try to run `rails s` I get the following error:

```
-bash: /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails: /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Where could this ruby-2.1.0 version be specified? I've looked at the `~/.bash_profile`, which looks like this:

```
PATH="/Users/myname/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

And the `~/.bashrc` which looks like this:

```
### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

But I can't find any of the versions. Maybe something is wrong with the content of these files? I wasn't able to find any good tutorial about this specific topic. Thanks.

**Update:**
Here is the gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" 
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails-i18n'

# pdf
gem 'prawn'

# charts
gem "google_visualr", ">= 2.1"

gem 'json'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

Here is the output of rvm list

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

ruby -v returns
`ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

**Update 3**
rvm reload shows:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353'.
```

**Update 4**
This is the output for

```
rvm get head
rvm 2.0.0,2.0.0@global do rvm gemset reset_env

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p353'.
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/myname/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/myname/.profile /Users/myname/.zshrc.
    RVM PATH line not found for Bash, run the installer with '--auto-dotfiles' to fix it.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/myname/.bash_profile /Users/myname/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/myname/.rvm/ is complete.

# myName,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:


  * WARNING: You have '~/.profile' file, you might want to load it,
    to do that add the following line to '/Users/nikolajandersen/.bash_profile':

      source ~/.profile

  * It looks like some old stuff is laying around RVM, you can cleanup with: rvm cleanup all

  * No new notes to display.

RVM reloaded!
Nikolajs-iMac-3:ergowerkstatt myname $ rvm 2.0.0,2.0.0@global do rvm gemset reset_env
gem gem-wrappers >=1.2.4 is already installed
gem gem-wrappers >=1.2.4 is already installed
Nikolajs-iMac-3:ergowerkstatt myname $
```

Comment: include the output of `rvm list`

Comment: I updated the question with the requested informations.

Comment: Try adding `#ruby=ruby-2.0.0-p353` at the top of your gemfile

Comment: I added it and ran `bundle install` but `rails s` but it's still the same error.

Comment: In a terminal leave your root directory and reenter it. This is rvm directive and is only executed when you enter to directory with a gemfile.

Comment: What does `ruby -v` return?

Comment: It returns `ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

Comment: Do you have any sort of .ruby-version file in that directory?

Comment: There is a .rvm file in my home directory (where bash_profile is) but it seems to be empty. There is nothing with ruby in the name.

Comment: you have specified ruby `ruby '2.0.0'` in the **Gemfile** either remove it, or use only the version

Comment: what the `bundle exec ruby -v` returned? if the same error, just comment out the `ruby 2.0.0` declaration.

Comment: do `rvm reload` and then `ruby -v`

Comment: rvm reload gives me a warning message, I updated the question with update 3. `ruby -v` now shows me `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]` but `rails s` still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh and I commented out the ruby version in the gemfile.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are setting ruby version in your gemfile as opposed to using a .rvmrc file to specify ruby version via rvm?

Comment: Well, when I started learning rails, I read that the gemfile is the place to set the ruby version. I've never read something about writing the ruby version into a .rvmrc file is the correct way. If this is the better way, I will write it there.

Comment: @JulioGMedina I believe specifying the ruby version is required for heroku-like systems... for development they are mostly useless

Comment: @LinusAn ok there is the problem with your PATH variable, look into the `.bash_profile` is you use bash on MacOSX, and make sure that after the rvm loading there are no more additionals to PATH variable.

Comment: How exactly should the file look like? I've posted the content of the files in the question.

Comment: After the line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`; put `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` to **.bash_profile**, and remove the two last line belonging to `rvm` from **.bashrc**

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, unfortunately it didn't fix the error.

Comment: @LinusAn have you reopen the terminal? If yes show PATH.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46265/discussion-between---and-linusan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you very much to everyone who helped me on this. I finally "fixed" this issue somehow, after the following steps:

- installed ruby 2.1.0 again
- removed it again
- removed 2.0.0
- reinstalled 2.0.0
- brew doctor

Finally after these steps everything worked properly. Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
rvm get head
rvm 2.0.0,2.0.0@global do rvm gemset reset_env
```

it will update RVM to latest version and reset environment/wrapper files for both `default` and `global` gemsets for ruby `2.0.0`, this should solve your problem, if it does not then you might be hitting a new bug, please open a bug here then: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution. I'll post the terminal output as update 4.

Answer (score 0):

Do 'which ruby' on terminal. On my system, there was a symlink in '/usr/bin'. Could also be in '/usr/sbin'. Correct it to point to the correct path.

Comment: `which ruby` gives me `/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby`. I think it is the correct path, right? I'm no expert in symlinks and related stuff.